# Email-client with Sent emails from many emails under IMAP?

Tags: email, imap

I am struggling to set up graphical email-client program in Debian, more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186005/graphical-email-client-with-sent-emails-directory) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182414/where-do-sent-emails-go-in-evolution). I have a similar problem with Android. I would like to see Sent -emails in my android phone. How can I see my sent -emails in my Android -phone from many email -addresses?

**Profile**

> I use IMAP. I have currently many devices such as laptop, Android and iPad -- to manage the same emails (some odd lag every-now-and-then). I have many email -addresses connected with apps such as Gmail -app by Google and [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) where I use IMAP.

Comment: Where is the problem? I use multiple IMAP accounts with mentioned K-9 on my Android. As sent mails are stored to the Sent folder (which is something you must configure), I can see them from either client: Android, Linux, Web...

Comment: Izzy absolutelly correct. IMAP invented for such usecase.

Comment: @hhh See below -- I put it into an answer, as it would be too long for a comment. Feel free to upvote and accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with IMAP mails are stored centrally on the server, you can see all mails from all IMAP clients. You can automatically store sent mails to a "Sent" folder (instead of only send them and *not* storing them), which is configured on a per-client basis.

I cannot tell for your desktop clients how to do this, but with K9 you can select the folder in

*Menu → More → Settings → Account settings → Folders → Folder for Sent objects*

Just in the *Folders* menu, you will find some more special folders you can define (e.g. for drafts).

Having your "Sent" folder defined **on all your clients** (and **always having defined the same**), you should be able to easily view your sent mails from all clients, regardless of the fact from which client a mail was sent.

Comment: *grin* I know why I wrote that. Just was missing some of my sent mails (had to setup a new computer a few month ago, as the old one said "Goodbye"). Forgot to adjust the Sent folder on that one, so they were only stored locally on that computer (but luckily at least they were stored)... Glad it helped you!

Comment: Lolz `Where is the problem?` -- hilarious question at the start ^_^ My answer covers the procedure to fix the problem with IMAP -profile. The key is your bolding from which I realized how to fix things. I had to do a lot of changes and over different devices, took years' work but got things much simpler, victory! I also got many Evolution -issues solved, more [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182414/email-client-such-as-evolution-with-sent-emails-folder) but it has some malfunctioning things such as Wastebasket.

Comment: Oh, welcome to the club. I also solved some of those, but still have others open (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150860/evolution-in-precise-laggy)) which are really nasty -- but going deeper is surely OT here ;) Besides: The "hilarious question" was not meant sarcastic, but as real question (which I luckily could guess the answer for a few minutes after asking it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I built on top of Izzy's comment

> Having your "Sent" folder defined on all your clients (and always having defined the same), you should be able to easily view your sent mails from all clients, regardless of the fact from which client a mail was sent.

It really means that every client -- I mean every -- such as Mutt in Server, Evolution in Desktop, K9 in Android, Online settings such as Gmail-labels/filters, iOS email more [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63537/how-can-i-specify-the-sent-folder-for-gmail-on-ipad), desktop settings such as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186283/how-can-i-change-wastebasket-folder-to-trash-folder-in-evolution) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186005/graphical-email-client-with-sent-emails-directory) -- must have corresponding settings. If one part is missing, your IMAP mailbox won't work over multiple devices or it has limited capabilities.

I gather below some errrors that I had to fix in order for IMAP work over multiple devices.

**Walk-through**

> 1. `'You have sent a message in a trashed conversation...'` -- fix this error in Gmail, more
>      [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=91097).
>      It may be because of filters or wrong setups.
> 2. Gmail folders are called `"Labels"`, make sure you have cross in a visibility -button, more
>      [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63537/how-can-i-specify-the-sent-folder-for-gmail-on-ipad).
> 3. In mutt, make sure you have the record line correctly like this: `set record=/home/users/hhh/mail/Sent`
> 4. In iPad, make sure this [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63537/how-can-i-specify-the-sent-folder-for-gmail-on-ipad)
>      again and make sure `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars >
>      Your@Email.com > Account > Advanced > Sent` corresponds to your other
>      settings -- not something like `Sent Emails`.
> 5. In Desktop, make sure your Desktop client has right settings more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186283/how-can-i-change-wastebasket-folder-to-trash-folder-in-evolution),
>      [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182414/where-do-sent-emails-go-in-evolution)
>      and
>      [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186005/graphical-email-client-with-sent-emails-directory)
>      (Debian -biased questions).

Next time you may have the same problem with other folders such as `Trash` and `Deleted Messages` -- yes I know -- it is irritating that different email-clients use inconsistent terminology so you need to adjust every name and delete all extra folders/labels later.

I hope you luck, my setup looks to work but I am still fighting with a minor issues such as removing extra directories in K9, anyone knowing a solution to that?

Comment: ...wrote [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182414/email-client-such-as-evolution-with-sent-emails-folder) how I got things running in Desktop.